# How to initialize Directwrite IDWriteTextLayout properly in a Direct2D window

Tags: c++, winapi, directwrite

I'm trying to write text to my `ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* renderTarget`-window using Directwrite. That works good and text appears where it should. But i have the feeling i'm doing something wrong in `Graphics::DrawMyText`. I think I should create my `IDWriteTextLayout* textLayout` also in the `Graphics::Initialisation` but if I do that, i cannot alter the text `const wchar_t* wszText` anymore. At least, I did not find any helper function in `IDWriteTextLayout` interface

So is it correct to create and release my `IDWriteTextLayout` all the time, or is there a way I only have to create it once like the other interfaces?

```cpp
#include<dwrite.h>

class Graphics
{
    IDWriteFactory* writeFactory;
    IDWriteTextLayout* textLayout;
    IDWriteTextFormat* textFormat; 
}

Graphics() // constructor
{
    writeFactory = NULL;
    textLayout = NULL;
    textFormat = NULL; 
}

Graphics::~Graphics() // destructor
{
    if (writeFactory) writeFactory->Release();
    if (textLayout) textLayout->Release();
    if (textFormat) textFormat->Release();
}

bool Graphics::Initialise(HWND windowsHandle)
{
    res = writeFactory->CreateTextFormat(
    L"Lucida Console",
    NULL,
    DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_REGULAR,
    DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
    DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
    10.0f,
    L"en-us",
    &textFormat
    );
    if (res != S_OK) return false;

    return true;
}

void Graphics::DrawMyText(const wchar_t* wszText, float x, float y, float boxWidth,
                          float boxHeight, float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
    writeFactory->CreateTextLayout(wszText, (UINT32)wcslen(wszText), textFormat,
                                   boxWidth, boxHeight, &textLayout);
    brush->SetColor(D2D1::ColorF(r, g, b, a));
    renderTarget->DrawTextLayout(D2D1::Point2F(x, y), textLayout, brush);
    textLayout->Release(); // don't forget this one to prevent memory leaks
}
```

Comment: Where did that `renderTarget` come from?

Comment: If you change the text, you'll have to recreate the layout, but you can keep the format, which is what you do. You could also cache the layout until the parameters to CreateTextLayout change. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/text-formatting-and-layout

Comment: @MariusBancila render target is initialised and defined elsewhere, but that's not relevant for this question but I listed its name and type.

Comment: `CreateTextLayout` takes in a text string and produces an object that represents the fully analyzed and formatted result. If you want to change text string content you can call `CreateTextLayout` again with new text string.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT thanks for your suggestion. That is what I do in the code shown, but I was hoping i could create `IDWriteTextLayout` once and reuse it like the other `ID`-elements.

Comment: *The text in an `IDWriteTextLayout` object cannot be changed once the object is created. To change the text you must delete the existing object and create a new `IDWriteTextLayout` object.* Refer to [Text Formatting and Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/text-formatting-and-layout#idwritetextlayout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text of a DWrite layout is indeed fixed, your choices are either to create (and release) layout objects or go the much harder route of using IDWriteTextAnalyzer (along with IDWriteTextAnalysisSource/IDWriteTextAnalysisSink). It would have been nice if the text of a layout were mutable but MS simply didn't make that choice.

Comment: Yeah, it would have been possible to add an `IDWriteTextLayout::SetText` and corresponding `IDWriteTextLayout::InsertRange/DeleteRange` function pretty easily (and hindsight says we should have), but we basically had two kinds of customers then (a) the simple app that wanted to draw mostly static text repeatedly (b) the low level customer that owned their own text backing store and had enough desire to call the low level text analysis API's directly.

Comment: I actually find uniscribe far easier to deal with than DWrite. Mostly because uniscribe can still honor the GDI SetTextAlignment setting and you can thus use baseline alignment and have the rendering engine deal with having text appear as if it's on a single line. (IDWriteTextLayout will do that but doing it with IDWriteTextFormat is a real pain).